# How to sort array when variable names have quotes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a vue.js front-end feature that could filter data by keywords and sort data in either ascending or descending order. And I found this code online which might meet my requirements. However the format of its data array is different from my retrieved array:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <br /><br />
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="filterValue" placeholder="Filter">
      <button @click="invertSort()">Sort asc/desc</button>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Value</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr v-for="data in filteredAndSortedData">
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.val}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        testData: [{name:'3', val:'a'}, {name:'2', val:'b'}, {name:'1', val:'c'}, {name:'4', val:'d'}],
        error: "",
        errorFlag: false,
        filterValue: "",
        sortAsc: true
      };
    },
    computed: {
      filteredAndSortedData() {
        // Apply filter first
        let result = this.testData;
        if (this.filterValue) {
          result = result.filter(item => item.name.includes(this.filterValue));
        }
        // Sort the remaining values
        let ascDesc = this.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
        return result.sort((a, b) => ascDesc * a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
      }
    },
    methods: {
      invertSort() {
        this.sortAsc = !this.sortAsc;
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

So in the provided function its array is like `testData: [{name:'1', val:'a'}]`, however, my array which retrieved by using `this.testData = response.data` in `function(response)` is like `testData: [{"name":"1", "val":"a"}]`
That being said, my variable names are double-quoted and cannot use the code I want. Is there a way to convert `[{"name":"1", "val":"a"}]` to `[{name:'1', val:'a'}]` (like removing variable names quotes) or sort it without modifying the array?

Comment: You can equivalently use `object['property']` instead of `object.property`

Comment: `Is there a way to convert [{"name":"1", "val":"a"}] to [{name:'1', val:'a'}]` those are identical as far as javascript is concerned. In both cases, the keys are strings and the values are too. Did you encounter any problem when trying to run the sorting code?

Comment: `let a = [{'"name"':"1", "val":"a"}]; a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a).replace(/"\\"name\\""/g, '"name"'))`

Comment: Using `object[property']` works for me but it only works in the example code. If I apply it on my retrieved array it outputs nothing.

Comment: `getData: function() {
        this.$http.get('url')
          .then(function(response) {
            this.testData= response.data;
          }, function (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.errorFlag = true;
          });
        }`
Above is how I get data from the server and `<tr v-for="data in this.testData">` does output something. However if I try `<tr v-for="data in filteredAndSortedData">` it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get object key sting using

```
var a = [{"name":"1", "val":"a"}];
console.log(a[0]["name"]) 
// if you already know key
console.log(a[0].name)
```

and this `[{"name":"1", "val":"a"}]`  and  `[{name:'1', val:'a'}]` is same in javascript.